# how to extract a multiple json objects within objects

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read a list of episodes (http://epguides.frecar.no/show/bigbangtheory/) from a json file, count the episode titles and print them in the console. However since I'm new to working with json I can't even manage to reach the first title, always returning null. A little help or a small hint towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

try {     

    File tmpDir = new File("src/bigbangtheory.json");
    boolean exists = tmpDir.exists();
    if (exists==true) System.out.println("file exists"); 
    else System.out.println("file doesn't exist");

    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/bigbangtheory.json"));

    JSONObject season =  (JSONObject) obj;
    System.out.println(obj);              

    Object title = (Object) season.get("title");
    System.out.println(title);        

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use Jackson parser. Might be easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON file contains an object holding all seasons.

From that object you need to extract a specific season and episode before you're able to read a title.

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/bigbangtheory.json"));

JSONObject seasons = (JSONObject) obj;
System.out.println(seasons);

JSONArray seasonTwo = (JSONArray) seasons.get("2");
System.out.println(seasonTwo);

for (Object o : seasonTwo) {
    JSONObject episode = (JSONObject) o;
    Object title = episode.get("title");
    System.out.println(title);
}
```